# Getting error in one hot encoding function implemented using np.eye()

Tags: python, numpy, one-hot-encoding

My test and train directories are following

- train
- --class_0
- --class_1
- test
- --class_0
- --class_1

train    --class_0    --class_1 
 - test    --class_0    --class_1

all classes contain 2 images as of now for testing as well as training.

I'm using following code to get one hot encoding for output labels

```
def convert_to_one_hot(Y, C):
  print ("hehe ",Y.reshape(-1), np.eye(C))
  Y = np.eye(C)[Y.reshape(-1)].T
  return Y
```

In the main program I'm passing C=2 and Y= [1 1 2 2]  and in doing so I'm getting the following error:

```
---> 55         Y = np.eye(C)[Y.reshape(-1)].T
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

I'm not able to rectify this error. Please Help!

Comment: Valid indexes for a 2x2 array are `[0,1]`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! it worked